# ¿Oracle ha cerrado las descargas de Netbeans 8.2?

Tags: oracle, netbeans-8.2

Hola he intentado descargar NetBeans 8.2 desde la pagina de Oracle y me redirige a otra pagina, este link debería mandar a la descarga https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-3413139-esa.html pero manda a otra donde no he podido encontrar nada sobre esta descarga, antes descargaba netbeans desde aqui  https://netbeans.org/downloads/8.2/rc/ pero ya no funciona ya que manda a las versiones de apache(Netbeans 9-12.3) . Alguna idea de como hacerlo ahora? Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Esto se debe a que la migración de `Oracle Netbeans` a `Apache Sotware Fundation` ya ha finalizado, al parecer con la última actualización de la página de Oracle dejaron de tener disponible el binario de Netbeans 8.2, esto era de esperar que sucediera porque Oracle daría un tiempo mientras Apache implementaba todas las funcionalidades a su versión después que Oracle cedió el desarrollo, como recomendación deberías de utilizar la versión de `Apache Sotware Fundation` ya que la 8.2 ya no tiene soporte de actualizaciones y nuevas tecnologías hace mucho tiempo, si aún necesitas la versión 8.2 por algún motivo especifico te dejo un link en mega para la descarga porque no se puede obtener por canales oficiales:

> https://mega.nz/file/9aJhTYxa#vgitzVc5oiBZrUZTifDfE701KGUVkYNHQdnBLeG3BDg